# Batch File set FOURTH=&

Tags: batch-file

Hi I'm kind of new to batch files and I was wondering if u pros could help me with something that seems simple enough.`set FOURTH=&` After running this I realized that FOURTH was not being set to "&". If there is a way, I would like to know how to set FOURTH to & without extra characters. I already tried `set FOURTH=^&` which I thought would work, again new here (first question). If there isn't a way but u can think of something that might help that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for do not use `^` (carets) is:

`set "FOURTH=&"`

But you need use `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at top of batch file, then invoke as:

`Echo !FOURTH!`

Comment: P.S: Remeber that `FOURTH` contains an `&`, if you use `%` instead `!`, you will get errors! You're welcome.